# SBT doesn't recognize properly its own classpath

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

Have a look at the snippets below.

This is my ultra simple app:

```
object EchoServer extends App {

  println(com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load())

}
```

Code above does what it is expected to do: displays configuration taken from reference.conf (which can be found in akka-actor.jar) merged with env variables.

Now have a look at my Build.scala:

```
  import sbt._
  import Keys._          
  import com.typesafe.config._

  object Build extends Build {

    println(com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load())

    lazy val XXXProject = Project(
      id = "x-x-x",
      base = file("."),
      settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        organization := "a.b.c",
        version := "0.0.1",
        scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
        crossPaths := false
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
          "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.2",
          "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

Here, after SBT was launched, the configuration is also displayed but it contains only env variables. It didn't parse reference.conf! **Why?** And how to deal with it?

I am planning to start an ActorSystem from inside of SBT and this problem is a major blocker for me.

I can do a workaround - copy reference.conf to my project, etc. but I am looking for more elegant solution.

More data for the curious:

plugins.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0"
```

build.properties:

```
sbt.version=0.13.2
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that I have to use *right* classloader (not the one provided by SBT):

```
val classLoader = ActorSystem.getClass.getClassLoader
println(com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(classLoader))
```